# how to map over the list of map and add them?

Tags: elixir

I have a list of maps something like this

```
    iex(84)> a                                                            
[
  %{a: 1, b: 2, c: [%{x: 1, y: 2}, %{x: 2, y: 3}]},
  %{a: 3, b: 4, c: [%{x: 2, y: 3}, %{x: 2, y: 3}]},
  %{a: 5, b: 6, c: [%{x: 3, y: 4}, %{x: 3, y: 4}]}
]
```

I'm trying to get a result like this

```
  [
  %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 8},
  %{a: 3, b: 4, c: 10},
  %{a: 5, b: 6, c: 14}
]
```

not able to map over the values of "c" and if I do I'm losing the initial map. What should I do?

Comment: Please specify tags carefullyu. This question has nothing to do with [tag:phoenix].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) with map update syntax to replace the `c` key:

```
input = [
  %{a: 1, b: 2, c: [%{x: 1, y: 2}, %{x: 2, y: 3}]},
  %{a: 3, b: 4, c: [%{x: 2, y: 3}, %{x: 2, y: 3}]},
  %{a: 5, b: 6, c: [%{x: 3, y: 4}, %{x: 3, y: 4}]}
]

for map <- input do
  %{map | c: Enum.flat_map(map.c, &Map.values/1) |> Enum.sum()}
end
```

Output:

```
[%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 8}, %{a: 3, b: 4, c: 10}, %{a: 5, b: 6, c: 14}]
```

Comment: hi. Can this handle more than 20K records in the list?. I can have more than that also. So how do i test this or you can tell what is best. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the input we should modify deeply nested elements. There is the greatest extremely underrated way to deal with that: [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html).

```elixir
input = [
  %{a: 1, b: 2, c: [%{x: 1, y: 2}, %{x: 2, y: 3}]},
  %{a: 3, b: 4, c: [%{x: 2, y: 3}, %{x: 2, y: 3}]},
  %{a: 5, b: 6, c: [%{x: 3, y: 4}, %{x: 3, y: 4}]}
]
```

Here we would modify all the elements of the input, updating `:c`. So we need to get to `[Access.all(), :c]` and call [`update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3) on them.

```elixir
update_in(input, [Access.all(), :c], fn x ->
  Enum.reduce(x, 0, & &2 + (&1 |> Map.values() |> Enum.sum()))
end)
#⇒ [%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 8},
#   %{a: 3, b: 4, c: 10},
#   %{a: 5, b: 6, c: 14}]
```

I believe the internal sum might be done in some more elegant manner, but that’s not the point. The point is: use `Access` here (and literally everywhere you operate on nested enumerables.)

Comment: `x |> Enum.flat_map(&Map.values/1) |> Enum.sum()`

Comment: I am not an expert in screwdrivers, I nail all the screws with a sledgehammer aka reduce :)